# Extracting text from scanned pdf (images) using Python PyPDF2

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, data-extraction, pypdf

I have been trying to extract text from a scanned PDF (images with non selectable text).

But, I am getting an out put which is not a human readable.

I want the information which contains DATE, INVOICE NO from pdf link(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qQsqhlSKTZs-hlswrV8PIirR36896KXZ/view).

Please help me in extracting and storing the same in plain text.

```
import PyPDF2
from PIL import Image
pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(r'document.pdf', 'rb')
page = pdf_reader.getPage(85)
if '/XObject' in page['/Resources']:
    xobject = page['/Resources']['/XObject'].getObject()
    for obj in xobject:
        if xobject[obj]['/Subtype'] == '/Image':
            size = (xobject[obj]['/Width'], xobject[obj]['/Height'])
            data = xobject[obj]._data
            print("*******", data)
            print(xobject[obj]['/Filter'])
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[UPDATED]
I don't think PyPDF2 can read text from images...
To turn images into text I would suggest going with some OCR tool like [PyTesseract](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract).
Here's an example using [pdf2image](https://github.com/Belval/pdf2image) and PyTesseract to achieve what you're looking for (you need to first correctly install PyTesseract/Tesseract and pdf2image):

```py
import pdf2image
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output, TesseractError

pdf_path = "document.pdf"

images = pdf2image.convert_from_path(pdf_path)

pil_im = images[0] # assuming that we're interested in the first page only

ocr_dict = pytesseract.image_to_data(pil_im, lang='eng', output_type=Output.DICT)
# ocr_dict now holds all the OCR info including text and location on the image

text = " ".join(ocr_dict['text'])
```

Comment: I am getting NameError: name 'Output' is not defined. Can you please specify what is Output

Comment: my bad, forgot to import it. Need to add `from pytesseract import Output, TesseractError` - updated my answer